# What happens on hash collisions for, e.g., transactions, blocks, and contracts?

Tags: cryptography, yellow-paper, hash-algorithm

> What happens on hash collisions for, e.g., transactions, blocks, and contracts?

What happens if, say, two transactions hash to the same value? In this case, we say that a hash-collision occured.

I've tried looking at the yellowpaper.io for an explanation, but can't really find the details.

Since the transaction hash serves as the transaction's identity, I don't see how Ethereum should allow multiple transactions with the same hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transaction hashes are 64 hexadecimal characters. This means there are `16 ^ 64 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936` possible transaction hashes.

Currently, `77752349` Ethereum transactions have occurred. If you create a new transaction now, the chance of its hash colliding with a previous transaction is:

`77752349 / 16^64 =` `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000067148 %`

You are more likely to win the jackpot in a national lottery 8 times in a row.

This doesn't really answer your question, but just looking at the probability we have better things to worry about :-)

Comment: Thanks, so if a collision occur, the EVM specification doesn't mention what should happen?

Comment: @Shuzheng It doesn't have to mention anything because the chance is so small. If you want to know for sure, you will have to read the source code, or ask a wallet developer. It may vary by implementation: geth may do something different from Parity. I would guess that the transaction would fail. In that situation, you would have to send a different transaction first to increment the nonce of your address. Then, you can do the transaction you wanted to do because it will have a different hash.

Comment: That makes sense to increase the nonce and try again. I don't agree that it doesn't have to mention it, since the probability is small. Would you like the whole blockchain to go into a corrupted state with small probability?

Comment: @Shuzheng There is a much larger chance that a huge electromagnetic eruption on the sun will wipe the blockchain from all hard drives. The specification doesn't have to mention this either.

Comment: OK! - you get a +1, and I will accept the answer, if no others can say what the specification suggests :-)

Comment: Actually it is pretty easy to create transaction collisions. From the Yellow paper `hash=keccak(nonce, price, gas, to, value, data)`. If two addresses send the same amount to the same address at the same price with the same nonce they will produce the same transaction hash.

Comment: @Ismael Nope, the transaction hash (a.k.a. txid) that is used to identify a transaction (e.g. on etherscan.io) includes the data you mentioned, but also the transaction signature, which is different every time. You will not be able to create a collision.

Comment: @JesseBusman I hope so, then Have I found another ganache bug?

Comment: I am wondering that if a collision occurs between a block B and a previous block A, then the data from A can be copied over B (or vice-versa), what should disrupt the chain and corrupt the transactions for those blocks. Besides, both blocks A+1 and B would point to "two" previous blocks instead of only one (B+1 points to B and A, A+1 points to B and A). Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: I found a reddit thread about someone the encountered a possible Tx hash collision: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6o1b9y/new_tx_hash_collision/