# Transaction collisions problem

Tags: transactions

As discussed at [What happens on hash collisions for, e.g., transactions, blocks, and contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29936/what-happens-on-hash-collisions-for-e-g-transactions-blocks-and-contracts), collision is not a huge problem.
From the probabilistic point of view it is highly unlikely to get collision hash.

But what if we will get exponential growth of transaction number dew to web3 extensive development. Imagine. Kettles, pans, sensors - all of them produce transactions.
At some point the probability of collision will reach some reasonable value, and taking into account the law of large numbers, collisions will become a problem.

Is there solution?

Comment: You'll have other issues to deal before collisions might appear. Using the birthday paradox for collisions to have a worrying probability you'll need around 2^128 hashes. The blockchain storage would have to grow 2^128 / 10^12 aprox. 3.4x10**26 terabytes.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a problem for the far future (relative to technological advancements.

It may take decades for this to be a problem to worry about. In the mean time, it's not that recommended to think too far into the future in terms of software, because many things can change, and thinks that we are prepared for may never happen or happen another way.

For example, the [Unit Time Epoch](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) is represented in a 32-bit number, which was alright for the people who started using this format decades ago, but will be a problem in the year 2038, because all computers still use the 32-bit number in that year, will overflow and the time will be wrong. Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#:%7E:text=Consequently%2C%20if%20a%20signed%2032,on%20Tuesday%2C%2019%20January%202038.).

It's obvious that it will need to be updated, but there's no rush to do it now, that's still a problem for the future.

Fo hash collisions, it's the same. We know that at some point the chances of hash collision may increase, but we also know that that is too far. Many things can happen before then. The blockchain ecosystem may stop existing, or the protocols may change completely, who knows?

In the future, if the transaction hash collision starts to be a problem, then the blockchain protocols may change, hard fork or whatever is necessary, to change the hash format, size, etc.

Decades ago a 64-bit number was considered somewhat secure, but not anymore and everybody stopped using them. The same will happen with larger numbers and they stop being secure.

This is not a problem to worry about now. A 160-bit number and 256-bit number are still unfathomably huge numbers, the chances of collision are really small, and will still be really small for many years to come.